# XslCompiledTransform cannot load stylesheet, expects token '}'

Tags: c#, xml, xslcompiledtransform

I have a XML that contains the following line:

```
 <Field Text="%%=$summ,{0:0.000}%%%" />
```

XslCompiledTransform.Load is expecting '}' instead of ':'.

```
 Expected token '}', found ':' in %%=$summ,{0 -->:<-- 0.000}%%%
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces are used for *attribute value templates* in XSLT.

The XSLT processor evaluates their content as an XPath expression, and `0:0.000` is not valid XPath.

If you mean literal curly braces, they must be escaped (in attribute values only, of course):

```
<Field Text="%%=$summ,{{0:0.000}}%%%" />
```